# UIViewController's delegate var becomes nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have already read all articles but could not find a solution. I have a class to organize navigation between controllers:

```
class Navigator: NotesListViewControllerDelegate {

var rootController:UINavigationController!
lazy private var notesListController:NotesListViewController! = {
    let controller = NotesListViewController(nibName: String(NotesListViewController), bundle: nil)
    controller.title = "Notes"
    return controller
}()

init() {
    self.rootController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.notesListController)
    self.notesListController.delegate = self
}

//MARK: NotesListController delegate

func plusButtonDidSelect() {
    print("plus button did select")
}
```

}

My `NotesListController`:

```
protocol NotesListViewControllerDelegate:class {
    func plusButtonDidSelect()
}

class NotesListViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate:NotesListViewControllerDelegate? {
        didSet {
           print("delegate = \(delegate)")
        }
    }
```

System shows in `didSet` what variable has setted. But in `viewDidLoad` `self.delegate` is already has `nil` value. What could be a problem?

**EDIT:** my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let navigator = Navigator()

    if let window = self.window {
        window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        window.rootViewController = navigator.rootController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

**EDIT 2** I resolved this problem by taking out `navigator` variable from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to other class variables (it becomes like strong property in obj-c). But why system not keeps it in memory when it was declared localy in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Comment: Where do you instantiate Navigator ?

Comment: @Leonardo in `appDelegate` class. It sets up `rootViewController`.

Comment: For which view controller viewDidLoad you're talking about?

Comment: @IshmeetSingh `viewDidLoad` of `NotesListViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is maintaining a reference to your Navigator instance ?

The NotesListViewController instance only has a weak reference so if nothing else keeps the Navigator alive, it will go out of scope and the delegate variable will go nil in notesListController (which I assume is being referenced elsewhere because it is being presented)

Comment: The navigator variable in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was local to the function so it went out of scope as soon as the function finished.   Because it was the only one maintaining a reference to the Navigator() object,  this caused the delegate to go nil.  Moving the variable in a larger scope (e.g. the appDelegate) maintains it alive beyond the function call.

Comment: Had the exact same problem. All I needed to do is save the created navigator to a local var in AppDelegate for it to work.